# Why do I keep corrupting the chain state after many RPC calls?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development

I’m experimenting with the blockchain, writing a block indexer / local node monitor.

In my testing I wrote a small python script that uses AuthServiceProxy.batch() to get the hash of each block.

After several hundred thousand, maybe even pushing a million RPC calls I’m finding my chain state is corrupted.

Bitcoin Core will just crash on load and I have to reindex the whole blockchain, this has happened twice now.

Is there something I’m doing wrong?

Comment: From my experience, your hardware needs to be in perfect operating condition or this type of thing can happen. No overheating, memtest, and quality ssds or nvmes (wouldn't trust hdds). Even the Bitcoin Core download page says a node is so intense it can reveal bad hardware that nothing else will and I can confirm that as I just had to replace a memory dimm in one of my desktops that wouldn't sync a bitcoin wallet.